# standalone class, vcenter and xymatrix

Tags: standalone, xy-pic

Using pdflatex Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) and standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2

The following fails with "! Missing $ inserted.". Replacing standalone with article works as expected.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
$$
\vcenter{
\xymatrix{
A \ar[d] \ar[r] & B \ar[d] \\
C \ar[r] & D
}
}
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `vcenter`, neither `$$`. Use only `$\xymatrix{A \ar[d] \ar[r] & B \ar[d] \\C \ar[r] & D}$`.

Comment: Standalone supposed to not have a layout... so "double $" means something without sence for this documentclass. Use single $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `vcenter`, neither `$$...$$`.

Use **only** `$\xymatrix{A \ar[d] \ar[r] & B \ar[d] \\C \ar[r] & D}$`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
$\xymatrix{
A \ar[d] \ar[r] & B \ar[d] \\
C \ar[r] & D
}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be very hard to get rid of \vcenter, I don't have much control over the content (otherwise I wouldn't have xymatrix in 2018...). Fortunately replacing $$ by $ seems to be enough.

Answer (score 2):

The default of `standalone` is to typeset a horizontal box (`\hbox`, precisely). Hence the text is in “restricted horizontal mode”, where `$$` just means an empty math formula. Hence `\vcenter` is scanned in horizontal mode rather than math mode and an error ensues.

Of course `\vcenter` does nothing at all in `standalone`, nor math mode is necessary, because `\xymatrix` is perfectly legal also in text mode.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
  A \ar[d] \ar[r] & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r] & D
}
\end{document}
```

By the way, `\vcenter` is a wild beast and using it requires care. You're lucky enough that `\xymatrix` encloses the material in a `\hbox`, otherwise you'd be in trouble (try `$\vcenter{a}$` in a normal document).

In order to vertically center an `\xymatrix`, it's better to use

```
\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix{...}
\end{gathered}
```

which requires `amsmath`.