# Missing `$` inserted because of `\left`

Tags: math-mode, errors, standalone, delimiters

I was trying to use the answer from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287481/using-latex-to-generate-png-images-of-an-equation) to make a png of a math equation. I'm using the very simple file:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=800x800,outext=.png},border=1pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\[
a = \left\lceil\frac{b}{c}\right\rceil
\]

\end{document}
```

Which generates the error

```
! Missing $ inserted
<inserted text>
                $
l.6 a = \left
             \lceil\frac{b}{c}\right\rceil
```

Obviously this is an error with the actual `.tex` source itself, and doesn't really have anything to do with `convert`, but do note that I have the ImageMagick utilities installed and in working order. In fact, I was able to generate a simple png using the inline math environment.

Why doesn't \LaTeX like my `\left`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `$\displaystyle...$` instead of `\[...\]`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417837/4427 for an explanation.

Comment: @egreg that worked. Why though? I've written loads of LaTeX and I've always used `$$` or `\[` for multiline math. Also: can I do linebreaks inside of `$\displaystyle`? If you'd like to write up an answer that addresses these questions, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Standalone is a bit special. Not at pc, but have you tried the varwidth option? That might help.

Comment: Well, you should *never* use `$$` in LaTeX. For line breaks like in `align`, use `$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$`.

Comment: Oh, nvm, I just found the second half of your comment. I suppose this is probably a duplicate of that question, though I'd argue it's difficult for a newbie who doesn't know _why_ his stuff is breaking to find that answer.

Comment: @daleif `varwidth` let me use linebreaks (also I removed the `size` specification from my `convert` option), but doesn't do horizontal centering... I'll `\centering` and such and see where that gets me.

Comment: Center in relation to what exactly? You should probably reformulate your question to be a lot more specific

Comment: @daleif I've found that if you wrap it in a `center` env, the compiler will complain and insert a bunch of $, but if you give it <SHIFT>+R, <ENTER> when it runs into that error, it will actually spit out exactly what I want.

Comment: @daleif this actually goes beyond the scope of my original question - I have a much more complex set of equations I was trying to typeset, but I broke the problem down to the smallest needed to reproduce my problem to ask this question. Now that I've gotten my question answered, I wanted to go back to typesetting my original equations. I have 4 that I want to each have their own line, all centered horizontally in the image.

Comment: You are not answering the question? What is being centered here the mwe has nothing to center as it is one line. Again be a lot more specific, then perhaps people can give you better advise. Right now we're flying blanks because of limited information

Comment: @daleif don't worry, you answered my question. Frankly everything else like centering etc. is off-topic, and I shouldn't be asking in the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`standalone` is a bit special, because it's aimed at typesetting a single object for conversion to PNG (or other graphic format) or for later inclusion in another document. So its normal way of doing is making a box much like `\mbox`, where one cannot use `\[...\]`.

There's a simple way out use inline math mode with `\displaystyle` that makes formulas like between `\[` and `\]`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
a = \left\lceil\frac{b}{c}\right\rceil
$
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is to use `varwidth`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
a = \left\lceil\frac{b}{c}\right\rceil
\]
\end{document}
```

but beware this won't work with multiline alignments. For this you can use the “inner” forms such as `aligned` and `gathered`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\begin{aligned}
a &= \left\lceil\frac{b}{c}\right\rceil\\
  &= \left\lceil\frac{d}{e}\right\rceil
\end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the record, I was able to get multiline arguments to "work" inside of `\[..\]` with just `varwidth` (without `amsmath`), but to be fair it wasn't pretty and probably shouldn't be done.